# Using date function for SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having issues using the date functions in sql workbench.

```
CREATE TABLE exampletable (

    exampledate DATE DEFAULT CURDATE() not null,
    );
```

I've tried CURDATE(), NOW(), CURRENT_DATE, but it keeps saying you have an error in your sql syntax and underlines whatever date function I use. Any ideas on what my issue is?

Comment: `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` can be automatically initialized to the current time.  I am not aware that `date` can be.  You can refer to:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html.  So you can initialize to a constant, but not to a function, which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL doc at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html:

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a
>   function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP or (as of MySQL
>   5.6.5) DATETIME column. See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”.